# Production and Developer Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, developer, production

My company's Salesforce Org has everything(Data) in Production Sandbox. But the salesforce best practice would be to develop in developer sandbox and to deploy in production(Correct me if I am wrong). Our requirement is to have entire data in developer sandbox too.

1)How to integrate the data between these two (production nd developer)sandboxes?
2) We will be having weekly updates in production sandbox. How to keep data in sync between these two sandboxes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, your terminology is a little off. See [this link](http://cloud4good.com/announcements/salesforce-sandbox-and-how-to-use-it/) for an overview of the different sandbox types.

Secondly, you can't have production volumes of data in a dev. or dev. pro sandbox. That is not what they're designed for.

Thirdly, you can only refresh a full data sandbox every 30 days (unless you go through support to get your refresh interval reset, which is a pretty rare event usually). There are apps (such as [this](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wmCeEAI)) that sync data from Production to your full data sandbox but they are usually paid.

I would suggest reading [this PDF](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dev_lifecycle/salesforce_development_lifecycle.pdf) which will give you a good overview about how environments are usually set up in Salesforce development.